# Angular 2 export property which is string or null

Tags: angularjs, typescript, angular

Let's say I have a property that can be a *String* or *NULL*. So I thought about doing this in Angular 2:

```
export class Slide {
  ...
  link: string|null;
  ...
}
```

and then I get an error which says

> Type expected.

So, how can I tell Angular that my `link` property can be either *String* or *NULL*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`link: string;` is sufficient.

You can always store null in a property, whatever its type is.